# IE processing CSS differently on different pages

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm having some trouble with IE not reading all of my CSS on the homepage of a website that I'm editing. I've checked to see that it validates (it's still showing that some  tags aren't closed even though that's not true but whatever). I CANNOT get rid of the inline styles specifically because the content management system (Volusion) overwrites much of the code that I write, so I've been forced to write a lot of inline code. The CSS page is loaded so that the header region has the styles:

```
#header{ z-index:1; 
         width:100%; 
         opacity:.85; 
         background:rgba(200,200,200,.85); 

         /*For IE*/ 
         background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200); 
         opacity(0.85); }
```

I originally ran it without "background-color" because rgba(200,200,200,.85) should work with IE but in this case it isn't. In fact, even before I changed it to add 'background-color' the other pages were drawing from this CSS perfectly. The home page however reads background-color, but that's the only thing it takes from this. It is clearly reading from the Template.CSS file because it references it, however the opacity is not being used and the header is being placed after images which are 'fixed' and so should be hovering above those images. The same is happening to the other elements within the header. I have btn-group:first-child as having:

```
.btn-group a:first-child{ 
       border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; 
       text-decoration:none; 
       font-weight:bold; }
```

but none of these styles are applied on the home page. In fact .btn-group doesn't show up at all on the styles list. I know that it *can* read this because if you go to any other page of the website you'll see how it should look (it's nearly perfect). The homepage however doesn't work.

The page in question is found at www.giftonline.us , any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you examined the style using IE developer tools?  Go to your page in IE, and hit F12 (or Tools->Developer Tools).  Click on the mouse icon, then click on the element that you wish to inspect on your page.  The full css pertaining to your element should appear.  See if anything is out of place there-- it should be a good first step toward debuggin.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you using?

Comment: That's what I did and that's how I know that many of the CSS rules I wrote are either not showing up or being overwritten. I'm using IE9

Comment: I think it's kind of funny how stackoverflow treats the hashmark (#), used for ids in css, as a python comment, which uses # for single line comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is being forced into Quirks mode, because you have an invalid `doctype` that doesn't match the other pages. You need to use a valid `doctype` so that IE will display in Standards mode.

Currently you have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Try changing the `doctype` of the homepage to be the same as your other pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Once you have given the page the correct `doctype`, the CSS rules should work like they do on the rest of the pages.

And you are using invalid html to link to your CSS:

```
<link href="v/vspfiles/templates/tempTemplate/css/Imports.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

It should be changed to:

```
<link href="v/vspfiles/templates/tempTemplate/css/Imports.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!!!!! You saved my life and helped me learn something I didn't even know was a problem!!!!!!